# How to start graphical software on Tails?

Tags: tails, clear-net

The Firefox web browser is the only graphical software on Tails the user "clearnet" can start, or? If not, how?

PS: I know that to run software under the user "clearnet" is stupid, but ….

Comment: why you want to do that? why do you use Tails for this? - simply take some other distribution with a live-image (which are pretty much all current ones).

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Because I want to start a software that isn't running with tor, but its output is needed while Tails is running.

Comment: sounds like a strange operation... **be aware that you'll compromise your anonymity!**

Comment: @DJCrashdummy yes, I know.